# Convert a date into a specific format using PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime, format, php-7

I would like to convert a date that comes in the format **06.11.2017 um 18:30 - 21:30 Uhr** into the format **2017-11-06**. So everything should be cut off after 06.11.2017 and the remaining date should be output in the format **YYYY-MM-DD**.

Is there an elegant way to do that?

Comment: What have you tried on your own? Please provide your code, we can help you with.

Comment: Where does the date "come" from? A variable? a system function?

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: You can do it by using Explode function of PHP to cut the unwanted date and then change its format.

Comment: I have tried with the substr function to remove the unwanted parts. Unfortunately, it did not work out as I wanted. In the meantime I have decided on the solution of Danyal Sandeelo (see below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$date = "06.11.2017 um 18:30 - 21:30 Uhr";
$date = explode(" ",$date);

 if(array_key_exists(0,$date))
     echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date[0]));
```

**output: 2017-11-06**

- Explode the string
- Convert the first part to the desired format.

Comment: I have chosen your solution. Thanks a lot for this :). Thanks, of course, to all the others who have posted a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not elegant but easy to implement :

```
 function formatDate($date) {
     $date = explode(' ', $date);
     $date = explode('.', $date[0]);

     return $date[2] .'-'. $date[1] .'-'. $date[0];
 }

 echo formatDate('06.11.2017 um 18:30 - 21:30 Uhr');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `Explode` function of `PHP` to cut the unwanted date and then change its format.

Below PHP code can help:

```
<?php
$date = "06.11.2017 um 18:30 - 21:30 Uhr";
$dateArr = explode(" ",$date);
$wantedDate = $dateArr[0];
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($wantedDate));
echo $newDate;
// Output will be 2017-11-06
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your date string is always on that format, use [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to cut the string then format the date to `'Y-m-d'`

```
$date = '06.11.2017 um 18:30 - 21:30 Uhr';
$date = substr($date, 0, 10); // cut string to take date
$date = new DateTime($date);  // set string as datetime object
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');  // formatted date (2017-11-06)
```